# Need help fixing Oracle SQL Query to return Rows with max column values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, greatest-n-per-group

I am getting errors when I am trying to show the movie (s) with the most no. of reviews.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT movieName, Count(*) NoOfReviews 
FROM MovieReviews 
where  Count(*) NoOfReviews = (Select MAX(NoOfReviews)) 
Group by movieName
```

It keeps giving me an error but I am not sure why. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT movieName, Count(*) NoOfReviews 
FROM MovieReviews 
GROUP BY movieName
ORDER BY NoOfReviews DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

This gives you the movie with most reviews, ties included.

Note that the row limiting clause is available starting Oracle 12 only. In earlier vesions, one option is `RANK()`:

```
SELECT movieName, NoOfReviews
FROM (
    SELECT movieName, Count(*) NoOfReviews, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Count(*)) rn 
    FROM MovieReviews 
    GROUP BY movieName
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You filter the results of an aggregation query using a `having` clause.  That said, this is rather cumbersome to do with `having` and window functions are a better solution anyway:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT movieName, Count(*) as NoOfReviews,
             MAX(count(*)) OVER ()  as max_NoOfReviews
      FROM MovieReviews 
      GROUP BY movieName
     ) mr
WHERE NoOfReviews = max_NoOfReviews
```